# Garmin Health Api response is blank array

Tags: php, curl, garmin

Getting response array blank when using health wellness api of garmin and not showing any error just give a blank array i'm confused not getting any solution for this my code is

```
public static function get_garmin_health_data(Request $request)
{
    //  dd(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $garmin_consumer_key = env('CONSUMERKEY');
    $garmin_consumer_secret = env('CONSUMERSECRET');
    $twitter_access_token = $request->oauth_token ?? '';
    $twitter_access_token_secret = $request->oauth_token_secret ?? '';
    $twitter_version = '1.0';
    $sign_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');
    // $end_time = Carbon::now()->timestamp; // Produces something like 1552296328
    // $start_time = Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->timestamp;
    $start_time = strtotime('-20 hours');
    $end_time = time();

    // dd($start_time);
    // $time = $request->oauth_nonce;
    $time = time();
    // $post = '{"event":{"type":"message_create","message_create":{"target":{"recipient_id":"123"},"message_data":{"text":"Hello world"}}}}';
    $post = '{}';
    $url = 'https://apis.garmin.com/wellness-api/rest/dailies'; 
    $param_string = 'oauth_consumer_key=' . $garmin_consumer_key .
        '&oauth_nonce=' . $time .
        '&oauth_signature_method=' . $sign_method .
        '&oauth_timestamp=' . $time .
        '&oauth_token=' . $twitter_access_token .
        '&oauth_version=' . $twitter_version .
        '&uploadEndTimeInSeconds=' . $end_time .
        '&uploadStartTimeInSeconds=' . $start_time;

    //Generate a signature base string for POST
    $base_string = 'GET&' . rawurlencode($url) . '&' . rawurlencode($param_string);
    // dd($base_string);

    $sign_key = rawurlencode($garmin_consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($twitter_access_token_secret);

    //Generate a unique signature

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $sign_key, true));

    $curl_header = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode($garmin_consumer_key) . '", ' .

    'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($time) . '", ' .
    'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", ' .
    'oauth_signature_method="' . $sign_method . '", ' .
    'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($time) . '", ' .
    'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode($twitter_access_token) . '", ' .
        'oauth_version="' . $twitter_version . '"';
$url2 = 'https://apis.garmin.com/wellness-api/rest/dailies?uploadStartTimeInSeconds=' . $start_time . '&uploadEndTimeInSeconds=' . $end_time;        
     $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url2,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization:' . $curl_header,
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    dd($response);
    curl_close($curl);
    $res = json_decode($response);
```

please suggest a solution for this question, if it is possible to answer in php or curl request.

Comment: Perhaps you should add more options to the curl request so that you can analyse the curl errors / info for the request - even more useful information can be had if you enable advanced debugging features like `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` but I do notice that you have no options to deal with SSL connections

Comment: Also worth pointing out it that your function does not return a value no does it set a class property instead so is there more code that you omitted from this method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on this Garmin-health API and getting blank response(e.g:[]).
But i think so! i have zero activities in my profile that's why i'm getting this response.
[image: my profile screenshot]